# Show alert view when tap on phone number in web view with Swift

Tags: swift

I'm having a web view that displays a company's address and phone number and email. The current behavior is when the phone number is tapped it is then dialled immediately.

Is there a way for me to prompt an alert view to let user confirm the call? Instead of calling it immediately?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the function I use to initialize  an alert:

```
 func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (ACTION) -> Void in
        // self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        alert.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }))
    print("running Activityindicator code")
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and I call it like so:

```
self.displayAlert("Alert title", message: "alert message")
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Where do I call displayAlert()? Cause the phone number is in the web view, not a button or anything like that